# How to extend AdapterView to behave like LinearLayout filled dynamically by an adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview, android-adapterview

My problem is that I have a view that has to be scrollable, but I also need a dynamically filled list in that view. I don't want to use a ListView for that list because it is too expensive for my purpose and behaves very bad when it is in ScrollView.

What I would like is a LinearLayout view that is filled dynamically by an adapter. The way I want to go is to extend AdapterView, but so far I was not very successful.

My question is if you guys tried extending AdapterView, if you could provide some useful tuts or codebases of your own.

Comment: You could look at Gallery implementation: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/Gallery.java

Comment: can you tell us on why you want to do this, imean in terms of feature

Comment: I want a view which items are provided by the adapter, with all the advantages, like dynamically adding new items on notifyDataSetChanged, introducing headers and footers, separators, etc.

Comment: This is a great question, and I have the exact same scenario. I know this question is old, but would love to know what you did or if there is an SO article that answers this.

Answer (score 3):

Neil Davies has done great work for cover flow using adapter view

take look at his code this will definitely help you...

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html

Comment: Sorry this is not right for me, because:
1. Gallery is deprecated
2. I would like to make my own implementation of something like Gallery